Mockito is currently self-attaching to enable the inline-mock-maker. This will no longer work in future releases of the JDK
I get this warning while testing in Spring Boot:
Mockito is currently self-attaching to enable the inline-mock-maker. This will no longer work in future releases of the JDK. Please add Mockito as an agent to your build what is described in Mockito's documentation: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#0.3
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (/Users/lcnicolau/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.15.10/byte-buddy-agent-1.15.10.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Following the link at the end of the first line, it will ask you to add Mockito as an agent to your build:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>@{argLine} -javaagent:${org.mockito:mockito-core:jar}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

However, the warning is still displayed.
Using:

Spring Boot 3.4.0
Apache Maven 3.9.9
OpenJDK 21.0.4


Similar question: Getting "a java agent has been loaded" warning in intelliJ after upgrading JDK 17 to 21. Does passing -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading work for you? What about this answer?

Add the option -XX:+EnabledDynamicAgentLoading... that will solve the point... furthermore remove the manually call of the javaagent... check this: https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/10/2023-10-26-maven-jacoco-configuration/ (mockito will do it on it's own)...

I added the argument -XX:+EnabledDynamicAgentLoading and the number of warnings were reduced but the first line will not go away Mockito is currently self-attaching to enable the inline-mock-maker.. Can someone help me please?

Finally fixed, both in command line and IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). There are two different warnings, so the fix comes in two parts, you can try each argument on its own to see the effect:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/mockito/mockito-core/${mockito.version}/mockito-core-${mockito.version}.jar
            -Xshare:off
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

No need for -XX:+EnabledDynamicAgentLoading or maven-dependency-plugin.
All the credit goes to this and this answers.

Also, take a look at this to understand why some configuration might only work for the build tool or the IDE. So you should use a neutral configuration, otherwise you will need a different configuration for each.

I added the above XML snippet to my pom.xml and added the argument -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to the VM parameters. All warnings were cleared except the first line Mockito is currently self-attaching to enable the inline-mock-maker... The XML snippets didn't have any effect. Any help would be appreciated.

@tarekahf This works for Maven and IntelliJ IDEA, I haven't tested it in Eclipse, but your answer is essentially the same, so that should work as well. There is no need to use -XX:+EnabledDynamicAgentLoading or the maven-dependency-plugin.

I figured out the root cause of the problem. I have submitted an answer.

If you will run the test from Eclipse, you need to change the JUnit Run Configuration.
I added the following to Eclipse JUnit Run Configuration VM Arguments:
-Xshare:off
-javaagent:${env_var:userprofile}\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\5.14.2\mockito-core-5.14.2.jar

Change the path to match the location of the jar file on your local.
And all warnings were cleared with the test execution.
Below are the  configurations I used in pom.xml:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${org.mockito:mockito-core:jar}
                        -Xshare:off
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Note that I removed @{argLine} as it was causing the Maven Test goal to break. I didn't figure out why using @{argLine} causes the Maven Test build to fail.
I should have known that Maven and Eclipse are different animals that are not 100% integrated.

seems like byteagent is not recommended that is my understanding from the error message.
Try to explicitly attach using jvm arguments while running the test case.
